# How To Remove Everything From Codeblocks

Tags: compiler-errors, c++14, codeblocks, uninstallation

I Have Some Compiler and Other Settings Issue On Codeblocks, I Have Tried To Re-install With Different Versions, But The Settings Remains The Same, I dont Know in Which Settings I Have Messed Up , Now I Want to Uninstall Codeblocks in a Way That All it's Previous Settings and Configurations also Gets Removed, So That I Can Install Freshly. Thanks

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what you mean and very unlikely that anyone can help you. Read the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask section and reformulate your question so other people can understand.

Comment: I Have Edited...Hope Now You Can Understand